Im trying to run this code: cnn = BatchNormalization(renorm=True)(cnn)
But This error occurs:
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to BatchNormalization: {'renorm': True}.
And I need this "renorm=ture" .
Is there any other method to do so?
I tried with the latest version of tensorflow.
Which is tf_2.17.0.
But
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py in init(self, activity_regularizer, trainable, dtype, autocast, name, **kwargs)
264             self._input_shape_arg = input_shape_arg
265         if kwargs:
--> 266             raise ValueError(
267                 "Unrecognized keyword arguments "
268                 f"passed to {self.class.name}: {kwargs}"
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to BatchNormalization: {'renorm': True}
The issue stayed.

renorm parameter was removed in newer versions of TensorFlow/Keras. See this GitHub issue

This renorm argument with BatchNormalization() was available in Tensorflow 1.x which got replaced by training argument in newer Tensorflow 2.x versions which has Python boolean values - True/False.
These Python boolean indicating whether the layer should behave in training mode or in inference mode.

training=True: The layer will normalize its inputs using the mean and variance of the current batch of inputs.
training=False: The layer will normalize its inputs using the mean and variance of its moving statistics, learned during training.

Please have a look at the BatchNormlization() API for more details.
